# How to get the value of Terraform count

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I need to get the value of the `count` in Terraform code below so I can write a conditional statement in bash.

here is the `terraform`

```
resource "aws_instance" "kubernetes_master" {
  ami = "${var.ec2-ami}"
  count = 3
  instance_type = "${var.ec2-type}"
  key_name = "${aws_key_pair.public.key_name}"
  subnet_id = "${aws_subnet.kube-master-subnet.id}"
  vpc_security_group_ids = ["${aws_security_group.sg-kube-master-allow-ssh.id}"]
  associate_public_ip_address = true

  user_data = <<-EOF
              #!/bin/bash           

              # if count=0; then echo "done"; fi

              pwd
            EOF
}
```

So I want to print `done` if the `count=0`

How can I do this?

Comment: Does `length(aws_instance.kubernetes_master.*.id)` work?

Comment: Is it possible to do something like that inside a this `user_data` section?

Comment: No, you generally can't self-reference resources in terraform, and some would even try to evaluate before the targets existed. If `count` is set by a var, you can just reuse that var. I would highly recommend not doing k8s the "hard way" like this.

Comment: You can reference `count.index` to get the value inside the resource definition, but your intended usage doesn't seem to make sense (it seems like you're trying to use it for some sort of logging during resource creation, and that won't work).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `${count.index}` inside your user_data heredoc to reference the current count.

```
resource "aws_instance" "kubernetes_master" {
  ami = "${var.ec2-ami}"
  count = 3
  instance_type = "${var.ec2-type}"
  key_name = "${aws_key_pair.public.key_name}"
  subnet_id = "${aws_subnet.kube-master-subnet.id}"
  vpc_security_group_ids = ["${aws_security_group.sg-kube-master-allow-ssh.id}"]
  associate_public_ip_address = true

  user_data = <<-EOF
              #!/bin/bash           

              # if ${count.index} -eq 0; then echo "done"; fi

              pwd
            EOF
}
```

If the total count on the resource was 0 no aws_instance resource would be created and no user_data would be run.

Comment: I will try this and get back to you. thank you for this

Comment: My pleasure. Hopefully, it works. Like others have mentioned, you may be better off using EKS rather than deploying Kubernetes from scratch, but I imagine you may already have had that discussion with your colleagues and determined that this is your best or only option.